# Read from Vectors and assign to members of an object

Tags: c++

I read from an input file that looks like this:

T1  23  0

T2  50  6

T3  40  8

pushing back in the 3 vectors, process_id,  run_time, arrival_time

I have a class process //has the members string ID, int run_time, int arrival_time

The first element of the 3 vectors belongs to the 1st process object and so on.. To do so: is my problem..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include"process.h"

using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("C:/Users/Ejada/Desktop/input.txt");

    string line;
    vector<string> process_id;
    vector<string> run_time;
    vector<string> arrival_time;
    vector<process> p; //process is a class with members string ID; int run_time; int arrival_time

    while(file.good() && (getline(file, line)))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        string a, b, c;
        iss >> a >> b >>c;

        if(a != "")
        {
            process_id.push_back(a);
            run_time.push_back(b);
            arrival_time.push_back(c);
        }
        else break; 
    }
    // at this point I have 3 filled vectors

////////////////////////PROBLEM IS IN THIS LOOP////////////////////////////

    for(int i=0; i<process_id.size(); i++) //take from 3 vectors to fill each process object
    {
        p.at(i).ID.push_back( process_id.at(i)); //error no suitable conversion
        p.at(i).run_time.push_back (stoi(run_time.at(i)));// error expression must have class type
        p.at(i).arrival_time.push_back (stoi(run_time.at(i))); // error expression must have class type
    }

    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `p` vector is empty when you reach the loop, but the main problem is that the members of `process` aren't vectors.

Restructure your code like this:

```
while (getline(file, line))
{
   // ...
}

vector<process> p(process_id.size());  // Create vector with appropriate number of elements

for (int i = 0; i < process_id.size(); i++) 
{
    p.at(i).ID = process_id.at(i);
    p.at(i).run_time = stoi(run_time.at(i));
    p.at(i).arrival_time = stoi(arrival_time.at(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `p` vector is still empty when entering the second loop. Thus the `at` invocation is going to fail. Also it looks like you want to be assigning to the members of `p[i]` instead of using `push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

The vector p is currently emtpy, so 'p.at()' will not return anything. p contains 'process' class ojects with members ID, run_time and arrival_time - which are not vectors, so do not have a 'push_back' operation.
Try:

```
process entry;
entry.ID = process_id[i];
entry.run_time = stoi(run_time[i]);
entry.arrival_time = stoi(run_time[i]);
p.push_back(entry);
```